# Border em CSS está alterando o resultado de getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, css, css-border

Estou criando um *Snake Game* em JavaScript e para realizar as animações, detecção de colisão e outros, eu utilizo a função `getBoundingClientRect()`, para obter a posição `left` e `top` de um elemento do jogo.

Acabei de completar quase que todo o jogo e tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém ao adicionar um **border** no meu arquivo CSS para a div `<div id="game"></div>` que é onde o meu jogo executa, a minha cobrinha começou a se mover na diagonal.

```
#game{
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

Abaixo está o código do meu método que obtém a posição dos elementos do jogo e do método que move a cobrinha e define uma posição para os elementos:

```
getPositionOf: function(element){

    var game_rect = this.game.getBoundingClientRect();
    var element_rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    return {left: element_rect.left - game_rect.left, top: element_rect.top - game_rect.top};
},

move: function(){

    var head = this.body[0];  // Obtém a cabeça da cobra
    var {left: head_left, top: head_top} = this.getPositionOf(head);

    // this.direction.speed == [0, -10]
    head_left += this.direction.speed[0];  
    head_top += this.direction.speed[1]; 

    this.setPositionOf(head, head_left, head_top);

    // ...
},

setPositionOf: function(element, left, top){

    element.style.left = left + "px";
    element.style.top = top + "px";
}
```

Para ter certeza de que o problema estava neste método, ou melhor dizendo, na função `getBoundingClientRect`, eu coloquei dentro do método o seguinte código para verificar qual a posição da cobrinha que a função devolve ( tenha em mente que a cobra deve se deslocar para cima numa velocidade de 10px ):

```
if (element.className == "snake"){
    console.log(element_rect.left, element_rect.top);
}
```

O resultado disso no **console** ao executar a aplicação sem a borda:

```
448.5 258                          snake.js:42 
448.5 248                          snake.js:42 
448.5 248                          snake.js:42 
448.5 238                          snake.js:42
```

O resultado ao executar a aplicação com o **border**:

```
448.5 260                          snake.js:42 
450.5 252                          snake.js:42 
450.5 252                          snake.js:42 
452.5 244                          snake.js:42
```

A minha pergunta é, porque o retorno do `getBoundingClientRect()` muda ao adicionar um **border** para a div `game` e o que eu posso fazer para resolver o problema ?

Comment: Para quem deu voto negativo, é possível dar uma sugestão do que eu posso melhorar a pergunta ?

Comment: Antes de tudo, não foi eu que negativei. Sobre a pergunta, a borda faz parte do 'css box model', então ela altera o tamanho dos elementos e isso pode ser o motivo do seu bug. Mas, so olhando o seu código é dificil confirmar isso. Você vai precisar debugar isso, coloca uns breakpoints e compara o valor esperado das variáveis com o valor que elas efetivamente estão assumindo até encontrar a fonte do erro.

Comment: No elemento que tem a borda coloca no CSS dele a propriedade box-sizing: border-box isso vai fazer com que a largura da borda não se some a largura total do elemento, ou troque a borda por um box-shadow de 1px, pois a sombra não interfere no box-model

Comment: @hugocsl eu tentei fazer o que você disse e ainda não funcionou. Colocar no arquivo CSS o `box-sizing: border-box` não fez diferença alguma e o `box-shadow` não criou uma borda nos 4 lados, ele só criou borda em baixo e na direita.

Comment: Da uma estudada na propriedade do Box-Shadow que vc vai aprender a criar "borda" dos 4 lados...